# How to highlight the selected xml element in the preview?

Tags: java, android-studio

Is there a way in Android-Studio to highlight the location of an XML element/tag from the text file, in the preview so that i can visualize it's position ?

By default it works the other way around, when clicking on an element in the preview, it will highlight it in the XML text file, i'm simply looking for the opposite behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I ues android studio 3.2.1 
By default, what you want happened 
like this :
[when I click in "Temperature" > "text view " in XML become highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTKdT.png)